# Jmeter Flexible File writer , save data in csv

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am new to JMeter, I am trying to perform a sample test on an API, I am using CSV to get 'id' to be passed in the request body, I wanted to store all performance-related data in a CSV file, I came across plugin Flexible File Writer, the problem I am facing it write only txt file I wanted to desire data in CSV file is it possible and also needed to get one value from the response and 'id' that is been present in CSV file from where I am taking the input to store along with the result, the reason I need to know which request has taken most time.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of the listener, you can define a list of JMeter variables that will be written to the file in the JMeter property `sample_variables`.

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables

> JMeter supports the sample_variables property to define a list of additional JMeter variables which are to be saved with each sample in the JTL files. The values are written to CSV files as additional columns, and as additional attributes in XML files. See above for an example.

```
# Optional list of JMeter variable names whose values are to be saved in the result data files.
# Use commas to separate the names. For example:
#sample_variables=SESSION_ID,REFERENCE
```

So, in order to write your `id` to the csv file you could start JMeter with

`jmeter -J sample_variables=id`

which works without the Flexible File Writer, and for CSV as well as XML output format.

Answer (score 0):

[CSV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is a subset of text file:

> A comma-separated values (CSV) file is a delimited **text file** that uses a comma to separate values.

so your "desire" is very unclear as the format of the file produced by the Flexible File Writer is totally up to you, for example here is default configuration changed from tab-separated to comma-separated:

[image]

And textual representations:

```
endTimeMillis,responseTime,latency,sentBytes,receivedBytes,isSuccessful,responseCode,id
endTimeMillis|,|responseTime|,|latency|,|sentBytes|,|receivedBytes|,|isSuccessful|,|responseCode|,|variable#0
```

With regards to this last column, you need to define a [Sample Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables) like:

sample_variables=id

in *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

More information: [Using the JMeter Flexible File Writer Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin)

Comment: Thanks for the guidance I had implemented what you said, but the problem is while opening my CSV, I see some result posted on the header also , I had done the following implementation  endTimeMillis|,|responseTime|,|latency|,|sentBytes|,|receivedBytes|,|isSuccessful|,|responseCode|,|variable#0|\r\n